# Irregular message detection

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a simple extension that, based on certain user actions in browser, sends messages to a popup script which then in turn calls functions in a background script. I'm new to developing Chrome extensions so bear with me.

Currently, I have a setup that detects user actions in-browser with a content script, sends a message to a popup script, and that calls a function in the detected background page (or so I believe, I haven't gotten alerts or logs to display anywhere from the background.js).

My question is: why aren't messages being detected when sent from the background script, and is the function in my background script being called at all?

manifest.json

```
{
  ...
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "gamify.png",
    "default_popup": "user_stats.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["jquery.min.js", "contentscript.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ]
}
```

contentscript.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#page-container").click(function() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
      action: "Load"
    });
  });
});
```

//Popup script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();

  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    var action = request.action;
    if (action == "Load") {
      bg.initialize();
    }
  });
});
```

background.js

```
function initialize() {

  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    action: "Start"
  });

  chrome.storage.sync.get("initialized", function(data) {
    alert("BS: Get initialized: " data);
    //Do stuff here
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind putting this "proxy" code in a popup?

Comment: Further down the line I was planning on having the popup js handle message/data passing between the content and background scripts, while using that data for modifying elements within the display popup.

Comment: Bad idea. I will explain why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you doing this in a roundabout way?

Popup page only exists as long as it's shown; if the popup is not open, nothing will listen to your message and it will be lost. Since it is very fragile, it's not a good candidate for message routing.

So, step 1: remove the message routing from the popup. Ideologically, the background page is "always there", and handles most of the operations. You can control the display of the popup by, say, listening to `chrome.storage.onChanged`, or just different messages that make sense only to the popup.

---

However, you also have declared that the background page has `"persistent" : false`, i.e. it's an [Event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages). That means it's not *always* always there.

This will, by the way, cause `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage` to fail from time to time if the page is unloaded.

You have two options:

1. Remove `"persistent":  false`. Event pages are harder to deal with, so if you're new, you might want to skip it.
2. Read the Event page documentation carefully. It lists limitations you have to deal with.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain things for a newbie, much appreciated. I've been writing as I've been reading so progress in one area led to falling back in another. I'm going to spend more time working on things following your suggestions.